# Wordpress uploads files in a wrong path (wrong date)

Tags: wordpress, date, path

strange thing: When I want to upload a picture in my wordpress, the picture is stored in the uploads folder from september 2009, but the time is set correct in my wordpress (2013).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My FTP Account set the new files to "private", I just had to change it there.

Comment: I didn't get you. I have the same problem. Where did you make the change?

Answer (score 4):

Are you uploading to a post from 2009?

If so, this may explain (it's a feature not a bug):

"Using WP 2.8.4, when uploading new media files to a page or post that has already been published, the new file is added in the /UPLOAD_DIR/year/month/ directory that corresponds to the original page/post publication date, rather than the file upload date."

From: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10752